# How to fix a value error when using matplotlib to change the size of a scatterplot in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am trying to create a scatterplot using pythons matplotlib library, and I am using this one outside data set that is filled with car data. When creating this scatterplot, I am trying to plot data points of cars retail price as the y axis, City MPG as the x-axis, and then hoping to plot the different car dealer price sizes (all shown in the code below).

```
import csv
file = open("data_cars_2004 (1).csv", "r")
reader = csv.reader(file)
car_data = []
with file as f:
    next(f)
    for word in reader:
        car_data.append([word[0], word[9], word[10], word[14]])
f.close()

df = pd.DataFrame(car_data)
df.rename(columns={0: 'name', 1:'retail price', 2:'dealer price', 3: 'city mpg'}, inplace = True)

x = df['retail price'].sort_values().head(20)
y = df['city mpg'].sort_values().head(20)
size = df['dealer price']
plt.scatter(x, y, s=size)
plt.show()
```

But I somehow keep getting this error for my size (df['dealer price'] is supposed to be values of all the cars dealer prices in the data set "data_cars_2004.csv").

Here is the error:
[Value error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jVHF.png)

How can I fix this error or is there something I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You can't do things this way.  Your `x` data will contain the top 20 entries sorted by price.  The `y` data will contain the top 20 entries sorted by MPG, but the `x` and `y` values do not correspond to the same entries.  Your chart will be meaningless.  Even if you picked the first 20 dealer prices, it would be 20 different entries from `x` and `y`.  You need to rethink your plot.

Comment: If you want a scatter plot of the top 20 cars by retail price, you can do that.  Sort the WHOLE dataframe by price, then grab the top 20 rows, and plot them.  If you want a scatter plot of the top 20 cars by MPG, you can do the same thing.  You can't plot both of them at once.

Comment: Noting @Tim's points above that your plot won't give you any real information, you are getting an error because `x` and `y` have a length of 20, while the length of `size` is the same as your entire data frame. For matplotlib to compile your scatter plot, `size` must either be scalar (just a single value) or be the same length as `x` and `y`.

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv('data_cars_2004 (1).csv', usecols=[0, 9, 10, 14])`, `df.columns = ['name', 'retail price', 'dealer price', 'city mpg']`, `dfs = df.sort_values('retail price', ascending=False).iloc[:20, :]` and `dfs.plot(kind='scatter', x='retail price', y='city mpg', s='dealer price')`

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you for informing me of my mistake and how to adequately go about plotting in python everyone!